# Not understanding how target, #selector() and @objc is being wrongfully used in this code

Tags: swift

Could someone explain to me why this isn't working

```
class MyClass{
@objc func doSomething(){
        print("I did something");
    }
}
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: MyClass, selector: #selector(doSomething), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

----EDIT--------

Found out that this works instead

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: MyClass(), selector: #selector(MyClass.doSomething), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Could someone explain why target needs to be MyClass() and not MyClass and why it needs to be MyClass.doSomething and not doSomething. Cos I thought the target becomes the scope for the selector

Comment: target must be an object

Comment: What about reading the documentation for Timer.scheduledTimer... you are telling the timer what to do (selector) and when (timeInterval) but you must also say who should do it.

Comment: Why is the timer staying outside the class?  Where does it belong?

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code

```
    var timer : Timer?
    
    func timerstarter(){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(doSomething), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    
    @objc func doSomething(){
        print("I did something");
    }
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work because self is not defined